# Codeigniter Model using JOIN that results false when two WHERE's are combined

Tags: sql, codeigniter, model

I have two tables, the first table is `'data_table'` that contains all information like (name,address..etc.) the second table is `'members_table'` it contains the id's of the first table that are member of certain group like (group 1,group 2 and so on..) Now what I am trying to achieve is: I want to get all the `id's` from the `'data_table'` that are not member of a particular group queried. What I tried is:

```
 $this->db->select(); 
  $this->db->from('data_table'); 
  $this->db->join('members_table', 'data_table.id = members_table.id', 'left');   
 $this->db->where('members_table.id', NULL); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

This is my query to get all the names that are not yet in members_table that displays a result which is boolean TRUE but if added the line:

`$this->db->where('members_table.group !=', 'group1');`

And have my query like this:

```
$this->db->select(); 
$this->db->from('data_table'); 
$this->db->join('members_table', 'data_table.id = members_table.id', 'left');   
$this->db->where('members_table.id', NULL); 
$this->db->where('members_table.group !=', 'group1'); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

i get 0 result. The purpose of this is for example if i want to check who are not yet members of group1 but can be already a member of another group or not yet a member of any group at all. If I query:

```
$this->db->select(); 
$this->db->from('data_table'); 
$this->db->join('members_table', 'data_table.id = members_table.id', 'left');   
 $this->db->where('members_table.group !=', 'group1');
 $query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result_array();
```

I only get the results of the id's of the people that are member of group except group1 but with no id's of those who are not yet members of any group at all. What could be the best way for this? Any SQL line answers will be fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly the following should work

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("dt.*")
    ->from("data_table AS dt")
    ->join("members_table AS mt1","dt.id = mt1.id", "left")
    ->join("members_table AS mt2","dt.id = mt2.id","left")
    ->where("mt1.id",NULL)
    ->or_where("mt2.group !=","group1")
    ->get();
return $query->result_array();
```